# logging out when app is closed without proper logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I implemented login/logout in my web app using redux. If the email & password are correct, a token is stored in the redux store and the user is redirected to a private route `/panel`. I am using persist so the info is stored in localStorage (although it isn't visible).

When the user clicks the logout button, the token returned from the logout action is null. The user goes back to the login page & can no longer access the private routes. However, if instead of logging out, I simply close the app, when I come back next time, the privateRoutes are still accessible simply by adding `/panel`to the link since the token is still present.

How can I modify it in a way that even if the app is closed, the user automatically logs out? I read on SO that I could use `useEffect`to clear the token but I am not sure how and where exactly could I do that. Should I make another action? Since I already have one for the logout, it doesn't make sense.

This is my privateRoute:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => {
    if (store.getState().token) {
      console.log("From private routing: ", store.getState().token);
      return React.createElement(component, props);
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/404" }} />;
    }
  };
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent} />;
};
```

Here's a codesandbox showing how I fully implemented logout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-mountain-qk8x2?file=/src/helpers/privateRouting.tsx:114-508

Answer (score 1):

Items in localStorage will persist even after the browser is closed. If you want to clear out the token then you can add an event listener for the window unload event to your App component.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {  
  // clear out the local storage
});
```

Comment: When we store something in the localStorage manually, we do something like ```localStorage.setItem('token', accessToken)```. Then we can also see it in our localStorage and can easily delete it by using the keyword ```token```. However, in this case, how can I clear the token from localStorage if I never saved anything in it manually and used persist instead?

Comment: you can just dispatch the logout action. If you don't want it to persist between browser sessions why are you using persist to begin with?

Comment: Can you maybe edit the codesandbox and help me understand how exactly I can use the addEventListener to clear the token in this case?